# Android - custom button animation

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I'm tring to create an animation for a "Vote up" button similar to what you can find here www.materialup.com.
Pay special attention to the "+1" or "like" button under each element, it's a rounded button that will turn pinkish when clicked and a small arrow will slide up as you do so, the number inside the button will increase. 
I know more or less the internals of android but I've nerver worked on the UI side. How hard would something like that turn out to be?.
I have already a FAB (floating action button) defined. I'm just wondering how can I accomplish the annimation part.

Here's what I have so far:

fab_selector.xml

```
<ripple
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="#FF27A7DA">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ff237da9" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) class. You create an ObjectAnimator object using the static [ofFloat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#ofFloat(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20float...)) method and pass in the View object you wish to animate, and define which property (position, alpha, scaleX, etc.) should change over time. Or, use the [ofArgb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#ofArgb(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int...)) methods for color.

The [Android Property Animation documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) should help considerably as well.

Comment: thanks, but that seems a bit too complex, just to give you a little bit of context, I'm not even being able to draw the triangle on top of the number in the button. I'm really not very fond of working with XML

Comment: If you use ObjectAnimator, you don't need to define your animation in XML. What you should do is work on creating the visual elements and getting it to all look right, then work on animating the alpha or position properties.